# User Profile Synchronization not happening in SharePoint 2016

Tags: user-profile-service

I have created SharePoint site collection and when I am trying to add users to groups, People picker is not resolving the users of Active directory. I have created **User Profile service**, **Configured synchronization connection**, **Ran the Synchronization job** and also **started Profile synchronization**. 
Even though it showing **Number of User Profiles: 1** -> which is my system account

What are the other that I left out ? Any idea?

Thanks!!

Comment: what type of UPA sync you are using? Active Directory Import? did your account has proper permission on the AD? how many domains you have?

Comment: User Profile sync has nothing to do with the People Picker, so UPSA isn't your issue. Is this a multi-domain Active Directory scenario? Is the account running the Web Application a domain user account?

Comment: I am using Active Directory Import. Can you please tell where can I check whether current logged in User has proper permissions to AD ?

Comment: @TrevorSeward 
VM in which I have installed SharePoint is in the same domain. Even when I am creating the site collection I am unable to give the other user ID as site collection administrator except the system account ID.